# How is Data Table Worked?

Tags: javascript, laravel, datatable

Need help for activating several JS features, such as Show Data Entries, Search, Sort by, and Paginate.

I'm using Laravel 8.

[image: top of table]

[image: bottom of table]

**JS Datatable**

```html
// Call the dataTables jQuery plugin
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable();
});
```

**View Blade**

```html
@extends('back.index')

@section('content')
<main>
    ...
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="text-align: center;">
                                <th style="width: 10%">#</th>
                                <th style="width: 60%">Nama Kategori</th>
                                <th style="width: 30%">Last Updated</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        @forelse ($kategoris as $kategori)
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">{{$kategori->id}}</td>
                                <td><a href={{ route('kategoris.show',['kategori' => $kategori->id]) }}>{{$kategori->nama}}</a></td>
                                <td style="text-align: center;">{{$kategori->updated_at}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        @empty
                        <strong>Tidak Ada Data ..</strong>
                        @endforelse
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</main>
@endsection
```

**Controller**

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Kategori;
use RealRashid\SweetAlert\Facades\Alert;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class KategoriController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $kategoris = Kategori::all();
        return view('back.kategori.show',['kategoris' => $kategoris]);
    }
  ...
}
```

How to make it works?
I really get confused about this prob, how I solve this?
I'm beginner at JS, so I had no clue at all.

Comment: you should read this doc https://datatables.net/

Comment: Laravel has an official package for datatables https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/installation

Comment: @KamleshPaul I already read it before post this, but I couldn't find a great solution.

Comment: @EsTeAa thanks, finally I could solve this prob.

Answer (score 0):

Add JQuery above the datatables script. It's should look like below snippet.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

don't forget to add the datatables CSS too inside

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
     "ordering": true,
     "searching": true,
      "order": [1, 'asc'],
      "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 20, 50, 100],
                [10, 20, 50, 100]
            ],
    "pageLength": 10,
         

} );
```

Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Sadly, still stuck. T-T